# What is the best way to get BibTeX entries from ISBN number?

Tags: bibtex, best-practices

I was wondering if the members of the community would kindly share their wisdom in what is the best way to get BibTeX entries from ISBN number? I am currently using 
[this](http://manas.tungare.name/software/isbn-to-bibtex/) service but results leave much to be desired for. Before I start writing a script which will fix all "imperfection" of the above service is there a better way to get BibTeX references from ISBN? In particular I am interested in web-sites which scale well because I would just like to get BibTeX reference of the web with the script and be done with it.

Comment: Have you tried ottobib (`http://www.ottobib.com/`)?

Comment: What is wrong with the website that you are currently using?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you try [Lead2Amazon](http://lead.to/amazon/en/)?

Select `BibTeX`, enter your ISBN, and click on "set and search" -- done.

Sometimes you need to try other Amazon sites, e.g. when searching books of Herbert Voss ...

Comment: Lead2Amazon seems to have the most BibTeX fields. Many other sites don't include `totalpages`, `edition`, etc.

Comment: http://lead.to/amazon/en/ seems to be offline by now.

Comment: http://lead.to/amazon/en/ works for me, although it redirects to https://lead.to/amazon/com/

Answer (score 16):

### Search for ISBN and export to BibTeX

- Ottobib: http://www.ottobib.com/
- similar to Ottobib: http://manas.tungare.name/software/isbn-to-bibtex/

### Search in all fields and export to BibTeX

- needs many mouse clicks until you can export: http://www.citeulike.org/

### Famous but needs repair

- [lead.to/amazon](http://lead.to/amazon/en/) select `Amazon.co.jp` and Bibtex. This combination still works today.

All databases have many mistakes in the fields and you will have to double check always. But don't worry the major science journals provide bad BibTeX data too.

Comment: Did you bother to check which tool I was talking about in my original post? I didn't want to give the name but if you were following the link you would see that manas.tungare was the tool I was not 100% happy with. I tested Ottobib after Mico's comment.

Answer (score 5):

Update for April 2022:

- Ottobib is offline.
- [www.citeulike.org/](http://www.citeulike.org/) is a gambling website now.
- Bibtex has a working ISBN converter here: https://www.bibtex.com/c/isbn-to-bibtex-converter/

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a script a few years ago that will take in ISBN numbers and emit BibTeX entries.  See https://gist.github.com/DavidGriffith/5097431.  It's very handy when you're faced with a bunch of books and you have a barcode scanner of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally if you use [Jabref](https://www.jabref.org/)
you can search by ISBN and get bibtex using this option:

choose **BibTeX → New entry**.... In the lower part, there is the box **"ID-based entry generator".**

References:
https://docs.jabref.org/v/v4/finding-sorting-and-cleaning-entries/import-using-publication-identifiers/isbntobibtex
[image: Add entry using ISBN to get bibtex]